# Phonegap: android faster than ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, lag

I just developed an app with phonegap.
With Android is really fast, but with ios there are same lags, like when I click on a button, 
on ios it take about half second more than android.

Do you know anything about it ?

Thanks

Comment: As described, it could be anything.  What is the specific code that you're running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the fastclick.js plugin for your ios app. it eliminated any delays with the buttons for me. all you do is download the js file, link it, and then add this code to your js:

```
$(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

i believe this is where is got it from: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick